# exec: "python": executable file not found in $PATH on Arduino IDE

Tags: macos, arduino, path

So I'm trying to run this really simple code on my LCD display, using an ESP32.
When I compile the code in the Arduino IDE I get no errors.
But, when I try to upload it, I get the following error:

```
exec: "python": executable file not found in $PATH
Error compiling for board DOIT ESP32 DEVKIT V1.
```

I'm running the Mac OS Monterey, on an M1 MacBook Air.

I did find some information [here](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/whatever/exec%3A+%22python%22%3A+executable+file+not+found+in+%24PATH+Error+compiling+for+board+ESP32+Dev+Module.), but it wasn't what I was looking for, it was made for Ubuntu.
I do have python3 installed on my Mac but it goes to `/usr/bin/python3`
and Mac automatically installs python,
I want python3 to go to `/usr/bin/python`
Running `which python` returns `python not found` which is weird, because python should be preinstalled on Mac.
Any ideas how to fix this error, and is my way possible?

Thanks!

Comment: if the question is about python why is not tagged as python? `which python` will try to find python 2.X but you have python 3. try `which python3` or install python 2.X

Comment: I'm getting the same error, from what I can tell Apple removed python2.7 in their latest macos release which is what `python` was linked to before.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I encountered the same problem, but I solved it by executing the following command based on this issue.

`sed -i -e 's/=python /=python3 /g' ~/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/hardware/esp32/*/platform.txt`

https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/issues/4717#issuecomment-1070801525

Comment: I'm not sure if that's because of you're solution or because I reset my system files, but now it's working flawlessly, thank you very much!

Comment: Worked on macOS Monterey with Arduino IDE 1.8.19!

Comment: This worked for me. I use the M5Stack package, so had to replace `eps32` with `m5stack`.

Comment: That worked for me, Arduino 1.8.19. M1 macbook pro. Sparkfun Esp32 Thing

Answer (score 0):

python2 has been removed in MacOs Monterey 12.3. So the proper way is to reinstall python2 if you have an application that needs it.
But in case that your current script would work with python3 you may try add a symlink. But you need to add in `/usr/local/bin`

```
sudo ln -s /path/to/python3 /usr/local/bin/python
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo ln -s `which python3` /usr/local/bin/python
```

or

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python
```

MAC OS doesn't allow for symlinks in `/usr/bin` so you have to put the symlink in `/usr/local/bin` instead.

Answer (score -1):

Probably a soft link will do, try `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python`

Comment: It results in: `ln: /usr/bin/python: Operation not permitted`